# Reading XML from blob for Twilio-call

Tags: powershell, azure, blob, twilio

Considering following code, which is part of a larger powershell script. When the scripts is triggered, a phone call is made by Twilio to 'To' with a text (in the XML $MessagURL) that is read with a TextToSpeech-Engine.

```
$params = @{ To = $XmlDocument.Response.Dial; From = $number; Url = 
$MessageURL}
# Make API request, selecting JSON properties from response
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url -Method Post -Credential $credential -Body 
$params -UseBasicParsing
```

$MessageURL is an URL to an XML. The XML contains the data for the text that needs to be said when calling the numbeer 'To' (which comes from another XML).
When $MessageURL is to a private public webspace, everything works fine.
When i change the $MessageURL to a azure blob-location, then the Twilio-logic can't read/access the XML-file anymore. The XML on the blob-storage is also free accessable through the internet.

Anyone any ideas why the script has problems with calling an xml on an azure blob-storage?

Comment: Does the xml on azure identify itself as an xml i.e. contenttype: text/xml ?

Comment: yes it does, contenttype is 'application/xml'. Even switching to 'text/xml' didn't solve the issue

Comment: Twilio will, by default, make a POST request to retrieve the XML. If you make a POST request to your blob-storage URL what happens?

Comment: A post request to the blob didn't work. "Invoke-Webrequest -Uri "URL" -Method Post" was used. I looked to actively accept POST request by enabling the CORS in the blob, but still no luck. Even with a SASkey added to the URL TWilio is still unable to read the XML on the blob